# OpenCL: Can one kernel call the other kernel

Tags: opencl

Hi ,
I am trying to run the available convolution code in OpenCL.
I am having heterogeneous system with -
1) CPU
2) GPU
PFB my code base which is running in my system :

## convolution.cl

```
// TODO: Add OpenCL kernel code here.
__kernel 
void convolve(
    const __global uint * const input,
    __constant uint     * const mask,
    __global uint       * const output,
    const int                   inputWidth,
    const int                   maskWidth){

        const int x = get_global_id(0);
        const int y = get_global_id(1);

        uint sum = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < maskWidth; r++)
        {
            const int idxIntmp = (y + r) * inputWidth + x;
            for (int c = 0; c < maskWidth; c++)
            {
                sum += mask[(r * maskWidth) + c] * input[idxIntmp + c];
            }
        }

        output[y * get_global_size(0) + x] = sum;
}
```

and convolution.cpp -

//Convolution-Process of applying a 3×3 mask to an 8×8 input signal,resulting in a 6×6 output signal

```
    #include "CL/cl.h"
    #include "vector"
    #include "iostream"
    #include "time.h"

    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

// Constants
const unsigned int inputSignalWidth = 8;
const unsigned int inputSignalHeight = 8;

cl_uint inputSignal[inputSignalWidth][inputSignalHeight] =
{
    {3, 1, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3},
    {4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3},
    {4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2},
    {9, 8, 3, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0},
    {9, 3, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 9, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {3, 0, 8, 8, 9, 4, 4, 4},
    {5, 9, 8, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1}
};

const unsigned int outputSignalWidth = 6;
const unsigned int outputSignalHeight = 6;

cl_uint outputSignal[outputSignalWidth][outputSignalHeight];

const unsigned int maskWidth = 3;
const unsigned int maskHeight = 3;

cl_uint mask[maskWidth][maskHeight] =
{
    {1, 1, 1}, 
    {1, 0, 1}, 
    {1, 1, 1},
};

inline void checkErr(cl_int err, const char * name)
{
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << name
            << " (" << err << ")" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void CL_CALLBACK contextCallback(
    const char * errInfo,
    const void * private_info,
    size_t cb,
    void * user_data)
{
    std::cout << "Error occurred during context use: "<< errInfo << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc,char argv[]){
    cl_int errNum;

    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_uint numDevices;

    cl_platform_id * platformIDs;
    cl_device_id * deviceIDs;

    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;

    cl_mem inputSignalBuffer;
    cl_mem outputSignalBuffer;
    cl_mem maskBuffer;

    double start,end,Totaltime;//Timer variables

    errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);

    checkErr(
        (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) ? errNum :
        (numPlatforms <= 0 ? -1 : CL_SUCCESS),
        "clGetPlatformIDs");

    platformIDs = (cl_platform_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * numPlatforms);

    errNum = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platformIDs, NULL);

    checkErr(
        (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) ? errNum :
        (numPlatforms <= 0 ? -1 : CL_SUCCESS), "clGetPlatformIDs");

    deviceIDs = NULL;

    cl_uint i;

    for (i = 0; i < numPlatforms; i++)
    {
        errNum = clGetDeviceIDs(
            platformIDs[i],
            CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
            0,
            NULL,
            &numDevices);
        if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS && errNum != CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            checkErr(errNum, "clGetDeviceIDs");
        }
        else if (numDevices > 0)
        {
            deviceIDs = (cl_device_id *)malloc(
                sizeof(cl_device_id) * numDevices);

            errNum = clGetDeviceIDs(
                platformIDs[i], 
                CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 
                numDevices,
                &deviceIDs[0], 
                NULL);

            checkErr(errNum, "clGetDeviceIDs");

            break;
        }
    }
    if (deviceIDs == NULL) {
        std::cout << "No CPU device found" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
    {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,(cl_context_properties)platformIDs[i], 0
    };

    context = clCreateContext(
        contextProperties, numDevices, deviceIDs,
        &contextCallback, NULL, &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateContext");

    std::ifstream srcFile("convolution.cl");

    checkErr(srcFile.is_open() ? CL_SUCCESS : -1,
        "reading convolution.cl");

    std::string srcProg(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(srcFile),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    const char * src = srcProg.c_str();
    size_t length = srcProg.length();

    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &src, &length, &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateProgramWithSource");

    errNum = clBuildProgram(program, numDevices, deviceIDs, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    checkErr(errNum, "clBuildProgram");

    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "convolve", &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateKernel");

    inputSignalBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
        context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(cl_uint) * inputSignalHeight * inputSignalWidth,
        static_cast<void *>(inputSignal), &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateBuffer(inputSignal)");    

    maskBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
        context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(cl_uint) * maskHeight * maskWidth,
        static_cast<void *>(mask), &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateBuffer(mask)");

    outputSignalBuffer = clCreateBuffer(
        context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        sizeof(cl_uint) * outputSignalHeight * outputSignalWidth,
        NULL, &errNum);

    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateBuffer(outputSignal)");

    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(
        context, deviceIDs[0], 0, &errNum);
    checkErr(errNum, "clCreateCommandQueue");

    errNum = clSetKernelArg(
        kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &inputSignalBuffer);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(
        kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &maskBuffer);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(
        kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &outputSignalBuffer);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(
        kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), &inputSignalWidth);
    errNum |= clSetKernelArg(
        kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_uint), &maskWidth);

    checkErr(errNum, "clSetKernelArg");

    const size_t globalWorkSize[1] ={ outputSignalWidth * outputSignalHeight };
    const size_t localWorkSize[1] = { 1 };

    start = clock();

    errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
                                    queue,
                                    kernel,
                                    1,
                                    NULL,
                                    globalWorkSize,
                                    localWorkSize,
                                    0,
                                    NULL,
                                    NULL
                                    );

    checkErr(errNum, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel");

    errNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(
        queue, outputSignalBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0,
        sizeof(cl_uint) * outputSignalHeight * outputSignalHeight,
        outputSignal, 0, NULL, NULL);

    checkErr(errNum, "clEnqueueReadBuffer");

    end= clock(); - start;
    cout<<"Time in ms = "<<((end/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000) << endl;

    for (int y = 0; y < outputSignalHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < outputSignalWidth; x++)
        {
            std::cout << outputSignal[x][y] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Questions :
    I am having below doubts-
    1) When I am using device type as CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
    am getting 267 ms performance .When I am using CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU,execution time changed to 467 ms.
    I want to know that what is the difference between running a convolution code on a CPU without GPU and CPU with GPU (by selecting device type as CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU) .
    2) As I can see the convolution.cl file where there is a for loop which is executing 3 times.Can I call other Kernel for doing this operation from available kernel file ??

I am asking this question as I am new to the OpenCL coding and want to know that thing.

Comment: are you running your kernel on batches of input, or on only a single 8x8 input at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Both CPU & GPU are OpenCL Devices. So, by choosing CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, you are telling OpenCL runtime to compile kernel code to CPU assembler & run it on CPU. When you are choosing CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, kernel code is compiled to GPU assembler & executed on your video card. Ability to change device type without re-writing source code is of the main OpenCL features. It doesn't matter, does your CPU have integrated GPU, and / or discrete GPU is installed, you just pick available Device & run kernel on it.
2. For OpenCL 1.2 & older you can't call kernel from kernel. Dynamic parallelism is implemented in OpenCL 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question: you should vectorize the kernel so opencl can easily use SIMD feature of your CPU hence  unlock 4x(or 8x) more compute units per core.

```
__kernel 
void convolve(
    const __global uint8 * const input, // uint8 fits AVX(AVX2?) and uint4 fits SSE(SSE3?)
    __constant uint8     * const mask,
    __global uint8       * const output,
    const int                   inputWidth,
    const int                   maskWidth){

        const int x = get_global_id(0);  // this is 1/8 size now
        const int y = get_global_id(1);  // this is 1/8 size now

        uint8 sum = 0;                      // a vector of 8 unsigneds

        for (int r = 0; r < maskWidth; r++)
        {
            const int idxIntmp = (y + r) * inputWidth + x; 
            for (int c = 0; c < maskWidth; c++)
            {
                sum += mask[(r * maskWidth) + c] * input[idxIntmp + c]; //8 issued per clock
                 // scalars get promoted when used in direct multiplication of addition.
            }
        }

        output[y * get_global_size(0) + x] = sum;
}
```

dont forget to decrease total work threads by 7/8 ratio (example: from 8k threads to 1k threads). 
Please increase work per thread such as 50 convolutions per thread to increase occupation ratio of work units, then work on some local memory optimizations(for GPU) to get even better results such as 5ms per kernel..

On my AVX capable CPU, a simple matrix multiplication got speed up ratio of 2.4X going for 8-element vectorizations like this.

Running a kernel 3 times is not an issue if you offload enough work on it. If not, you should concatenate multiple kernels into a single one using some tricky algorithm.

If a profiler is not available at the moment, you can check GPU/CPU temperatures to get some idea of how close you are to the limits of hardware.

Play with number of local threads per work group. This can change performance as it lets more or less registers to be used per thread.

Comment: Generally I would say that either you unlock "**4x** more" or "**3** more" compute units (and would say that the first option is _much_ more commonly used).